# Missingdataerror: exog contains inf or nan while trying to fit an OLS model

Tags: missing-data, olsmultiplelinearregression

Trying to fit an OLS model but not successful.
2 responses were gotten as error:

- missingdataerror: exog contains inf or nan
- olsmodel1 not defined
  Below is my code:
  olsmodel1 =sm.OLS(y_train, x_train).fit()
  print(olsmodel1.summary())

I have checked for missing values using :
df1.isna().sum()

Here is the output:

```
brand_name               0
os                       0
screen_size              0
4g                       0
5g                       0
main_camera_mp           0
selfie_camera_mp         0
int_memory               0
ram                      0
battery                  0
weight                   0
release_year             0
days_used                0
normalized_used_price    0
normalized_new_price     0
```

I will appreciate of someone can help me out.
Thank you

I was actually expecting the OLS result to be generated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to fit a regression model using the code:                                                
olsmodel1 =sm.OLS(y_train, X_train).fit() ## Complete the code to fit OLS model
print(olsmodel1.summary())   Unfortunately I am having error